# How to use a Pipe (|) with indices like an Integral

Tags: math-mode

for [Antiderivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) we write something like this:`F\mid_{b}^{a}` but it doesn't look like it should. I want to have the indices a and b at the same position as they were at an Integral `\int_a^b`

Comment: You also have `\left. F \right|^a_b` for suppressing the left delimiter but keeping the right `|`.

Comment: That looks exactly like F\mid_a^b.

Comment: You may be looking for something like `F\bigm|_a^b` or `F\Bigm|_a^b`.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for. If you post this as answer, I'll flag it as the solution ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `\mid` macro does not let you adjust the height of the resulting "pipe" or vertical bar. To obtain taller vertical bars, while preserving the nice spacing before and after the symbol, use either `F\bigm|_a^b` or `F\Bigm|_a^b`.